# SignalR cannot read property client of undefined

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to add SignalR to my project (ASPNET MVC 4). But I can't make it work.

In the below image you can see the error I'm receiving.
[image]
I've read a lot of stackoverflow posts but none of them is resolving my issue.

This is what I did so far:

```
1) Ran Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre
2) Added RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); in Global.asax.cs Application_Start()
3) If I go to http://localhost:9096/Gdp.IServer.Web/signalr/hubs I can see the file content
4) Added <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> to Web.Config
5) Created folder Hubs in the root of the MVC application
6) Moved jquery and signalR scripts to /Scripts/lib folder (I'm not using jquery 1.6.4, I'm using the latest)
```

This is my Index.cshtml

```
<h2>List of Messages</h2>

<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion">
    </ul>
</div>

@section pageScripts
{
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/map.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

This is my IServerHub.cs file (located inside Hubs folder)

```
namespace Gdp.IServer.Ui.Web.Hubs
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
    [HubName("iServerHub")]
    public class IServerHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is map.js

```
$(function () {

    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
    var clientServerHub = $.connection.iServerHub;

    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    clientServerHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
        $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + name + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + message + '</li>');
    };

    // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
    $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));

    // Set initial focus to message input box.  
    $('#message').focus();

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
            // Html encode display name and message. 
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text($('#displayname').val()).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text($('#message').val()).html();

            // Call the Send method on the hub. 
            clientServerHub.server.send(encodedName, encodedMsg);

            // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        });
    });
});
```

The DLL's I see references for SignalR are:

1. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core
2. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin
3. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb

Any ideas how to get it work?
Should I make any change because the scripts are in /Script/lib folder?

**NOTE**
I'm following the instruction found [here](http://blog.mirajavora.com/signalr-dependency-injection) on how to set up Windsor Castle to make it work with SignalR, and again, seems that the proxy cannot be created and I'm getting the same error:

```
Cannot read property client of undefined
```

meaning that the proxy to the hub was not created

This is how I have it in the server

```
public class IncidentServerHub : Hub
```

and like this in the client

```
var clientServerHub = $.connection.incidentServerHub;
```

Again, I can see the dynamically created file here:

```
/GdpSoftware.Server.Web/signalr/hubs
```

So, why is the proxy not created?

Comment: You can try with `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>`

Comment: Same happens, anyways, I see the file content when a browse it from the browser.

Should I make any change because the scripts are in /Script/lib folder?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I fixed that problem by changing my js code from:
    `var myHub = $.connection.SentimentsHub;`
to
    `var myHub = $.connection.sentimentsHub;`

So if you have some hub with class name TestHub you must use testHub(first letter is lowercase) name in js

Comment: Thanks, this helped me realise my hub names did not quite match.

Comment: Its mentioned in the documentation
"Note
In JavaScript the reference to the server class and its members is in camel case. The code sample references the C# ChatHub class in JavaScript as chatHub."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: Its also called the `Camel Case` style! You made my day!

Answer (score 44):

For those who tried to add the generated proxy file path in the bundle.

**Do not include the "~/signalr/hubs" in your BundleConfig.cs**.

You can have the *JQuery.SignalR* in the bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/signalr").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js"));
```

But you will need to add *"/signalr/hubs"* it in your view:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalr")
    @Scripts.Render("/signalr/hubs")
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I struggled a lot with this. You saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: The dynamically generated hubs js file *was actually not created* until I properly referenced "/signalr/hubs"

Comment: MATE! I'd give you a plus 100 for this if I could.

Comment: Bro.... SOOOO Many hours saved. Thank you

Answer (score 21):

I had the same error message and resolved the issue by fixing a typo I had in the [HubName] attribute on the hub class - it was not exactly matching the property in the client-side javascript.

C# hub class:

```
[HubName("gameHub")]
public class GameHub : Hub
{
```

client-side javascript:

```
var foo = $.connection.gameHub;
```

"gameHub" must be the same.

hth

Answer (score 9):

**For ASP.Net MVC folks:**

Check your `_Layout.cshtml`: If you are calling the jquery bundle after the `@RenderBody()`, you will get this error.

**Resoultion:** Just move the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` to the head section **or** write all signalr scripts in the scripts "section"

Answer (score 5):

Your hub classes must be defined as public. For example:

```
class ChatHub : Hub
```

should actually be

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
```

Comment: Ouch!! That was it.  So glad you posted that.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've found the issue, one thing I needed to do was:

These two references were missing:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.AspNet
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.Common
```

Now, I included them getting nuget package: WebApiDoodle.SignalR which uses those two.
My question is why those Dlls weren't added one I installed the Nuget Package: 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre?

Bug?

Then I had this in my global.asax.cs

```
using SignalR;
```

so

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

was using that one, I needed to remove that using and use this one:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
```

So the MapHubs use that one, and started to work.

Hope this helps others.
Guillermo.

Answer (score 4):

You should put SignalR and jQuery scripts, in correct **order** :

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.js"></script>

<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I lost `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll & Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll` in my project. After adding References to them, that error was solved. it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add

```
app.MapSignalR();
```

inside startup.cs and Configuration method,
 like this:

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

> **For Asp.net Core**

Add

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

in ConfigureServices methode in your startup.cs

And add

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
            });
```

in Configure methode in your startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

Making the Hub class "public" solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, could be the wrong name given in the class and reference in JavaScript is wrong.

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;   //did not work

var chat = $.connection.myHub; // this worked
```

This is my class

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```