# SignalR: Cannot read property 'hub' of undefined?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to add **SignalR** into my MVC application. Every required script to initialize SignalR loading well and in correct order like

[image: Loading]

but still when i am trying to read the `$.connection.hub.start()` i am getting this below 
error

[image: Hub Error]

I am not getting what is going wrong here.

```
$(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
    $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
        console.log("HUB ERROR : " + err);
    });
    notebook.value('projectactivity', $.connection.projectactivity);
```

One more thing when i did `console.log($.connection)` into **jquery.signalr*.js** file i am getting the `$.connection` object into **console**.

Comment: may be this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179644/signalr-connection-is-undefined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324806/signalr-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-chat-of-undefined

Comment: i have already looked into these samples.

Comment: if $.connection is defined when jquery.signalr* is executed, but not in $.ready, then either something is explicitly setting $.connection = undefined, or you have jQuery included twice, as I explained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20352832/2001735

Comment: i just tried to add the code right after /signalr/hubs script and without inside $(function(){}) and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing to reference hub class.

```
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.YourHubClass;

       $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
         // initialization logic that has to occur after SignalR startup
       });

        $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
           console.log("HUB ERROR : " + err);
        });
    });
```

Comment: NO! I have tried your code sample with my Hub  Class and getting the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectActivity' of undefined`

Comment: have you observed error message has been changed "Cannot read property 'projectActivity' of undefined". what is "projectActivity"?

Comment: that is the name of my `Hub Class`

Comment: try putting hub class in lower case.
Example
var chat = $.connection.projectactivity;

Comment: NO! we can't because i have checked the proxy name in `~/signalr/hubs` and the name was `projectActivity`. One more thing i just tried to add the code right after `/signalr/hubs` script and without inside `$(function(){})` and it works

Comment: Please see this thread "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146913/signalr-cannot-read-property-client-of-undefined". This error is related to class name.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to init the start function a callback after signalR loaded, especially when the script is loaded dynamically rather than embedded in the document.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer