# SignalR Type Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using `signalR` in my project. But I 'm getting this error

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined'

my Code is

```
var notification = $.connection.CounterHubs;

notification.client.inboxMessageCount = function (c) {
    ViewModel.InboxMessages(c);
}
```

thanks for answer

Comment: What is your question? The error shown here is clear that `notification` is 'undefined' so it does not have property `client` on it.

Comment: Why its not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SignalR cannot read property client of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146913/signalr-cannot-read-property-client-of-undefined)

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is because your hub is written with an Uppercase.

From the documentation:

*In JavaScript the reference to the server class and its members is in camel case. The code sample references the C# ChatHub class in JavaScript as chatHub.*

So it should probably be:

```
var notification = $.connection.counterHubs;
```

See this page on getting Started with SignalR:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: Well spotted :)

Answer (score 0):

This tends to happen when you haven't included the automatically generated `hubs` file into your page.

Include the hubs file into your page:

```
<script src="http://example.com/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

If you have included it already, open your developer tools (F12) and check the value of `$.connection.CounterHubs;` in your code and verify that it is not 'undefined'.